# How can I switch the iPhone's screen/backlight on/off in my App

Tags: iphone, uikit, hardware, ios4

My app needs to go to sleep and wake up after a user specified time interval. Using

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
```

I'm ignoring the idle timer. For the "sleep-mode" I'm turning the view to all black and hide the status bar. Still there's the device's background-light. Is there a way to turn it off or hit a real sleep mode - and then have it wake up again still being logged in and displaying the app (without the "slide to unlock" screen)?

Thank you & kind regards

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't change the backlight programmatically in the iPhone SDK. However, I agree, it would be a useful thing.

Comment: Somehow I expected this. Thank you for the clarification, seanny.